# How do I fix an an error of - There is no entity type mapped to the table 'AspNetUsers' in migration files

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am just learning ASP.NET Core, I finished an API which has multiple users, each has a book with notes of pages assigned. During development I sort of forced my migration files to work, also editing multiple items straight in the database, as I made a user class first, and only after started adding identity, which at that point caused some problems.

However, now I want to publish the API and I was my migration file error caught up to me. I managed to fix some of them, however this one is really causing me a pain in the ass. The full error is:

> There is no entity type mapped to the table 'AspNetUsers' which is used in a data operation. Either add the corresponding entity type to the model, or specify the column types in the data operation.

I have 3 migration files, but this error seems to be occurring in the main one below, can anyone please help me? Thank you a lot.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

#nullable disable

#pragma warning disable CA1814 // Prefer jagged arrays over multidimensional

namespace NoteTakingApp.Migrations
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public partial class DatabaseCreation : Migration
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUsers",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                    UserId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(60)", maxLength: 60, nullable: false),
                    LastName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
                    UserName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    NormalizedUserName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    Email = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    NormalizedEmail = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    EmailConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                    PasswordHash = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    SecurityStamp = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    PhoneNumber = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    PhoneNumberConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                    TwoFactorEnabled = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                    LockoutEnd = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(type: "datetimeoffset", nullable: true),
                    LockoutEnabled = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false),
                    AccessFailedCount = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUsers", x => x.Id);
                });

            migrationBuilder.InsertData(
                table: "AspNetUsers",
                columns: new[] { "Id", "AccessFailedCount", "ConcurrencyStamp", "Email", "EmailConfirmed", "UserId", "LastName", "LockoutEnabled", "LockoutEnd", "NormalizedEmail", "NormalizedUserName", "PasswordHash", "PhoneNumber", "PhoneNumberConfirmed", "SecurityStamp", "TwoFactorEnabled", "UserName" },
                values: new object[,]
                {
                    { "19e2edf9-0d46-4aba-9695-3f5e4b60799a", 0, "c79421b1-0f88-4d5e-af7f-edf2dab55a36", null, false, "Petr", "Novák", false, null, null, null, null, null, false, "389e7bc2-9270-49fa-8bae-3b570b250c85", false, "TTester" },
                    { "ecba1a02-f0b8-4bb6-8268-460e6e382ef2", 0, "1f276fcd-e35f-40bc-9d13-38a1d86d8ce8", null, false, "Jan", "Novák", false, null, null, null, null, null, false, "67bcaf89-85d7-4170-9433-1aa473cb8018", false, "TTester2" }
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                    name: "AspNetRoles",
                    columns: table => new
                    {
                        Id = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                        Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                        NormalizedName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                        ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
                    },
                    constraints: table =>
                    {
                        table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoles", x => x.Id);
                    });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetRoleClaims",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    RoleId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                    ClaimType = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    ClaimValue = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoleClaims", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetRoleClaims_AspNetRoles_RoleId",
                        column: x => x.RoleId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetRoles",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable
                (
                name: "AspNetUserClaims",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    UserId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                    ClaimType = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    ClaimValue = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserClaims", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserClaims_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUserLogins",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    LoginProvider = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                    ProviderKey = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                    ProviderDisplayName = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
                    UserId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserLogins", x => new { x.LoginProvider, x.ProviderKey });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserLogins_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUserRoles",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    UserId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                    RoleId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserRoles", x => new { x.UserId, x.RoleId });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetRoles_RoleId",
                        column: x => x.RoleId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetRoles",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUserTokens",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    UserId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                    LoginProvider = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(450)", nullable: false),
                    Value = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserTokens", x => new { x.UserId, x.LoginProvider, x.Name });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserTokens_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });



            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_AspNetRoleClaims_RoleId",
                table: "AspNetRoleClaims",
                column: "RoleId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "RoleNameIndex",
                table: "AspNetRoles",
                column: "NormalizedName",
                unique: true,
                filter: "[NormalizedName] IS NOT NULL");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_AspNetUserClaims_UserId",
                table: "AspNetUserClaims",
                column: "UserId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_AspNetUserLogins_UserId",
                table: "AspNetUserLogins",
                column: "UserId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_AspNetUserRoles_RoleId",
                table: "AspNetUserRoles",
                column: "RoleId");

            //migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            //    name: "EmailIndex",
            //    table: "AspNetUsers",
            //    column: "NormalizedEmail");

            //migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            //    name: "UserNameIndex",
            //    table: "AspNetUsers",
            //    column: "NormalizedUserName",
            //    unique: true,
            //    filter: "[NormalizedUserName] IS NOT NULL");

            migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Books_AspNetUsers_userId",
                table: "Books",
                column: "UserId",
                principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Books",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    BookId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
                    Title = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(60)", maxLength: 60, nullable: false),
                    UserId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Books", x => x.BookId);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Books_Users_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "Users",
                        principalColumn: "UserId",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Pages",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    PageId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
                    Title = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(60)", maxLength: 60, nullable: false),
                    Layout = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(60)", maxLength: 60, nullable: false),
                    Order = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    BookId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Pages", x => x.PageId);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Pages_Books_BookId",
                        column: x => x.BookId,
                        principalTable: "Books",
                        principalColumn: "BookId",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });


            migrationBuilder.InsertData(
                table: "Books",
                columns: new[] { "BookId", "Title", "UserId" },
                values: new object[] { new Guid("7ba52cf3-a35c-4c47-b14d-800c5bcf6443"), "MyTestBook", new string("19e2edf9-0d46-4aba-9695-3f5e4b60799a") });


            migrationBuilder.InsertData(
                table: "Pages",
                columns: new[] { "PageId", "BookId", "Layout", "Order", "Title" },
                values: new object[,]
                {
                    { new Guid("b66d20c1-c142-4d43-aad1-5e346b0ddad3"), new Guid("7ba52cf3-a35c-4c47-b14d-800c5bcf6443"), "2x1", 1, "FirstPage" },
                    { new Guid("b66d20c1-c142-4d43-aad1-5e346b0ddad4"), new Guid("7ba52cf3-a35c-4c47-b14d-800c5bcf6443"), "1x2x1", 2, "SecondPage" },
                    { new Guid("b66d20c1-c142-4d43-aad1-5e346b0ddad5"), new Guid("7ba52cf3-a35c-4c47-b14d-800c5bcf6443"), "2x1", 1, "FirstPage" }
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Books_UserId",
                table: "Books",
                column: "UserId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Pages_BookId",
                table: "Pages",
                column: "BookId");
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "NoteEntities");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Pages");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Books");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Users");
        }
    }
}
```

I googled the error, made sure all Ids of users the books are using are assigned etc. I know that it is not the best practice to populate the database of users like this, but technically it should work. Also tried ChatGPT, but without any luck.

Comment: Hi @JProSSV, so it works fine on local machine but not working when hosting? Where do you host the application?

Comment: @Rena Hello, well it does not work anywhere. The thing is, my migration files were ok, but I implemented a user class first and only added identity after. I did something wrong because it screwed my implementation files. Then through trial and error I got it to work, but I think because I started messing around with my database manually I caused some discrepancies. Now I cannot Update-Database both when publishing and locally. Thank you for answering.